# What are the units for CloudWatch VolumeWriteOps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to estimate how much Aurora will cost. I need to know how many I/Os it will use. I have MariaDB running on an EC2 instance, and I thought I'd start with that to get an estimate. I created a dashboard on CloudWatch. Here is the widget.

[image: What are the units?]

I can't figure out something obvious: What are the units? I see around 5k write ops. PER WHAT UNIT OF TIME? Is that 5k write ops per minute, per hour, per second? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Also, it seems like a lot of ops, regardless of the units. Can you give me any insight?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using **VolumeReadIOPs** and **VolumeWriteIOPs** metrics? If so, they are documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.AuroraMySQL.Monitoring.Metrics.html

Unit of these metrics is *Count*, they count the number of operations. And the metric is emitted every 5 minutes. So if you're not doing any aggregations on the graph, values will be for 5 min intervals.